# Object transparency

Tags: transparency

I have a model of a spaceship. When I render the animation and use it in Lightworks, the rendered model allows the background to be seen through. These are the steps I took:
1. Render tab > Film > transparent checked.
2. Output tab > File format png > RGBA > 8bit

What am I doing wrong? I want the background to be a star field, but obviously I don't want that star field to be seen through the spaceship. Thanks

Comment: What is Lightworks?

Comment: Good morning, Lightworks is a video editing software (https://www.lwks.com/)

Comment: ok, so your problem is that you have rendered images of your spaceship with a transparent background, but when you put it in Lightworks, and add a space background, it shows through the spaceship?

Comment: I don't think this is a problem your having with blender, you didn't do anything wrong to my knowledge, I think this is something with Lightworks.

Comment: OK thanks mate. I will test some more in Lightworks and see if the settings for the star field effect are the issue. Cheers.

Comment: I found out what the issue was. It was actually when I was importing the png files in Lightworks. One of the settings I had was removing the Alpha channel. All is good now. Cheers everyone.